# how to get miner address from transaction hash

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, json-rpc

In ethereum private blockchain i want to get the miner address from transaction hash. eth.getTransaction and eth.getTransactionReceipt are not giving miner details. is there any way to get miner address and total number of transaction validated by miner.

Answer (score 1):

i got the the answer for getting miner details, we first need to get **blockNumber** from **transaction hash**, then we can call **eth.getBlock(blockNumber)** to get miner address for specific transaction